# Update UI with a 2 parameters event on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, wit-ai

I'm new to Unity and my problem seems very simple but I can't find an answer online.
I'm trying to implement VoiceSDK (speech recognition) on a Oculus Quest.
There's a event called OnError(string, string) automatically called by Wit when an error occurs. But using the inspector, I can't make these strings displayed in a TextMeshPro. I can only with event giving 1 parameter. The only functions I can use are "BroadcastMessage" or "SendMessage"...

[image: Event image]

Comment: You will need a custom component which handles these via a method like `public void HandleError(string a, string b) { ... }` and forwards them to your text components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said you can't directly set the `Text.text` via the event.

You will need a dedicated component on your `Text`s like e.g.

```cs
[RequireComponent (typeof (Text))]
public class ErrorHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Text _text;

    void Awake ()
    {
        if(!_text) _text = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    public void HandleError(string a, string b)
    {
        _text.text = a; // or b?
    }
}
```

And then in the drop-down you rather select this `HandleError` method from the **dynamic** ones.

---

Or alternatively you do the se but on this object itself and have a component like

```cs
public class ErrorHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Text buttonText;
    [SerializeField] private Text logText;

    public void HandleError(string a, string b)
    {
        buttonText.text = a;
        logText.text = b;
    }
}
```

and just reference your two texts accordingly